# I want to make an array of structure dynamically but I get a heap corruption error:

Tags: c++

Hello **stackoverflow** 
so my question is: I want to make a function to generate the array  of structures but i get an error whenever i finish inserting the values what is the problem?
like so

```
  struct INFO
{
    char name[20]; // creating the strucure
    int age;

};
void generateArr(INFO *p); // a function to generate the array
void readArr(INFO *p);    // a function to read the array
int main()
{

    INFO *ptr =new INFO; // a pointer that points to the structure
    generateArr(ptr);  // calling the functions
    readArr(ptr);
    delete[]ptr; // deallocating memory

}
void generateArr(INFO *p)
{
    p = new INFO [3]; // generating three INFO structures

 }
void readArr(INFO *p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        cin >> p[i].name>> p[i].age; // inputting the elements
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

I tried to make the code as clear as possible, ask me if anything is ambiguous.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You're only assigning to the parameter in `generateArr`. It has as much effect on the outside world as `void f(int x) { x = 0; }`.

Comment: You allocate memory for `ptr` in main and try to overwrite the pointer in `generateArr`. That would be a leak if it worked, but it does not because it is passed by value. That's also the reason your program crashes, `ptr` only has memory for 1 element in `readArr`.

Comment: Please stop trying to learn C++ by trial and error, it will get you nowhere. Learn it systematically from a good book instead.

Comment: heap corruption occured 
you wrote to memory after .....
sorry haven't memorized the entire message and im currently working on something else. @yankee2905

Comment: sorry i dont quite get your answer.
@molbdnilo

Comment: that's exactly what im doing, and i bloody hate c++ i have to study it though because of college i do love working with c#.
any good books recommendation though?
@BaummitAugen

Comment: If you have `void f(int x) { x = 0; } int main() { int y = 100; f(y); std::cout << y; }`, do you expect to see `0` or `100`?

Comment: right, but how to fix that @Unimportant

Comment: @AreyMSalih https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: i got it @molbdnilo im overwriting it , but dindnt know how to pass the pointer without intilizing it.

Comment: @AreyMSalih That's not my point at all; the point is that you're *not* overwriting it. (The `int` program will print `100`.) And you can always initialise a pointer to the null pointer.

Comment: I'm so tired today i had a two hour long exam, and tomorrow is OOP exam 
i got no time to rest their main concern is your marks not how much you know, sorry for not understanding your point earlier. @molbdnilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function :

```
void generateArr(INFO *p)
{
    p = new INFO [3]; // generating three INFO structures

 }
```

is not working as you expect it does. It assigns allocated memory to local 'p` parameter, which is not returned to a main. To fix it change p to reference:

```
void generateArr(INFO *&p)
```

[edit]

but since you already assigned `ptr` in main with `INFO *ptr =new INFO;`, you will get a memory leak this way. So you should remove that line.

Comment: And remove `=new INFO;` in `main`, otherwise it's leaked.

Answer (score 0):

In `generateArr(INFO *p)`, you allocate an array which address is stored in local variable `p`; on return from the function, any local variable (such as `p`) is lost, as long as address of the allocated array.

You should get rid of function `generateArr(INFO *p)`, which is useless, and allocate your array into `main()`, this way :

```
int main()
{
    INFO *ptr =new INFO[3];
    readArr(ptr);
    delete[]ptr; // deallocating memory
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the functions at least the following way

```
INFO * generateArr( size_t n )
{
    return new INFO [n]; // generating three INFO structures
}

void readArr(INFO *p, size_t n )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        cin >> p[i].name>> p[i].age; // inputting the elements
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

and in main call them like

```
const size_t N = 3;

INFO *ptr = generateArr( N ); // a pointer that points to the structure
readArr( ptr, N );
delete []ptr; // deallocating memory
```

As for your code then in this statement

```
INFO *ptr =new INFO; // a pointer that points to the structure
```

there is allocated only one object of the structure type however it is deleted using operator `delete []` instead of the operator `delete`.

```
delete[]ptr; // deallocating memory
```

And inside this function

```
void generateArr(INFO *p)
{
    p = new INFO [3]; // generating three INFO structures
}
```

there is a memory leak because variable `p` is a local variable of the function that was initialized by the value of the function's argument and that will be destroyed after exiting the function. As result the address of the dynamically allocated memory will be lost.